# Cumulative distribution function of continuous random variables

Tags: statistics, density-function

Marginal density functions: $f_{V}(v)=f_{W}(w)=\frac{1}{60}$

Joint density function: $f_{V,W}(v,w)=\frac{1}{3600}$, for $0\leq x\leq60$ and $0\leq y\leq60$

I need to find the cumulative density function of $T = W - V$

I'm thinking it's something along the lines of this:

$F_{t}(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & w-v<0\\ 
\frac{t}{60} & 0 \leq w-v \leq 60\\ 
1 & w-v>60
\end{matrix}\right.$

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: @DilipSarwate that answer is way above my head. What is a Jacobian?

Comment: Except for the random variables being $U(0,60)$ instead of $U(0.1)$,this question is a duplicate of [Problem with density of $X-Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/203477/15941) which has several answers. Don't just read the answer by Aang which is overkill. Both Did and I gave much more straightforward answers to the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of getting the density function…

1.) by convolution formuar

$V,W$ are independent RV (why?) so are $W$ and $-V$ and so the density of $T = W + (-V)$ is the convolution of the densities of $W$ and $-V$ which are known…

2.) $$f_T(t) = F'_T(t) = \int_{W-V \le t} f_{(V,W)}(v,w)\; dv dw$$ what can be calculated easily…

Comment: So are the results in my original post wrong? I used the convolution formula and got the same result and $\frac{1}{60}$ for the density function